# Can't call fragment method from activity

Tags: android, fragment

I have activity, that contains viewpager, with some fragment on the each tab. I want to call some method from fragment. I'm using:

android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

My code:
Main Activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends BaseTabsActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        initTabs();
        // call method here
    }
}

    public class BaseTabsActivity extends BaseActivity {

    protected void initTabs() {
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ProfileTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
    }
}
```

ProfileTabsAdapter:

```
public class ProfileTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ProfileTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment0();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 3:
                return new Fragment3();
            case 4:
                return new Fragment4();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.string0);
            case 1:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.string1);
            case 2:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.string2);
            case 3:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.string3);
            case 4:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.string4);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment0 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


    public String doSomething() {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's well described in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

For your convinience, here is relevant part of the code:

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
       getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

if (articleFrag != null) {
    // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

    // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
    articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
}
```

But please make sure and go read the docs I linked at the begining.

Comment: "article_fragment" is a id of root layout in fragment?
In my case, it returns null.